# How to set-up vicidial in local system?

Tags: vici

I want to set-up vicidial in my local computer server any information or a document for that?
I googled but I can't find exact resource.
I googled below links.

[Link 1](http://download.vicidial.com/ubuntu/VICIdial_for_Dummies_20100331.pdf)

[Link 2](http://astguiclient.sourceforge.net/vicidial.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is Vicidial? What are you trying to accomplish with it? Why did you add a tag for "sugarcrm?" I just searched for "vicidial" and found this site which boasts downloads, documentation and a live cd to try the software: http://www.vicidial.org/ -- what more do you need?

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource are off-topic here, which is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic]. A link to documentation would be classified as an "off-site resource". Google and Bing both specialize in searching for things and returning links to the results of that search.

Answer (score 3):

Vicidial is an Open Source Predictive AutoDialer based on Asterisk with PHP/MySQL/Perl coding.

Installation of Vicidial is only viable on a Linux machine.

There are several locations with Scratch Install instructions for Ubuntu and CentOS. In fact, the Vicidial Wiki has a list of a few of them: http://wiki.vicidial.org/index.php/VICI:Installation

Most are quite old except for the Goautodial.com which has instructions for CentOS installation by adding the goautodial repositories and then just upgrading the OS to get all the necessary packages.

If you're not using CentOS or Ubuntu and none of those instructions work for your purpose, beware that Vicidial installation is not easy. It is MUCH better to dedicate a machine to the purpose by installing from Vicibox.com's .iso image which will wipe the computer clean. The installation becomes easy and then you need only argue with configuration.

If you can not dedicate a machine to this purpose, you should take the earlier suggestion of a Virtual server (vSphere or Virtualbox both work for Vicibox.com's .iso installer), but beware that you'll only be able to have one or two agents on the virtual dialer at the most. Luckily, if you do get the virtual vicidial working, it is possible to backup the virtual server's database and install it on a hardware based server later to bring everything with you without having to do it all over.